# How to just use the polyamorous gem from ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

From looking at the code, the `ransack` gem has included a gem called [polyamorous](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/master/polyamorous/polyamorous.gemspec).  I only want to use the `polyamorous` functionality which extends ActiveRecord's associations to support polymorphic belongs_to
associations.

Given `ransack` takes quite a bit of memory, is there a way of just using the `polyamorous` gem in ransack?  There is a standalone version of [polyamorous](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/polyamorous) but it is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked in my `Gemfile`:

```
git 'git@github.com:activerecord-hackery/ransack.git' do
  gem 'polyamorous'
end
```

However, this does not work on Heroku due to incorrect permissions, so I would like to know if it is possible to also do this from `rubygems`.

It appears that the `ransack` team [intend](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/1038#issuecomment-511763441) to release a standalone gem.  In the mean time, you can put in your gem file `gem 'ransack', require: false` and

```
# config/initializers/ransack.rb
require 'polyamorous'
```

which means only the polyamorous code will be loaded from ransack.